# Binding hardcoded values and databases values into one dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a drop down list in C# asp.net MVC3 razor engine.
I need to load values to that dropdownlist from one of my tables in my database and some values are hard coded.
So I need to get both kind of values into one dropdown list.

I can do them separately.

This is how my view is :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MyTransaction.Status, new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.MyStatusId, "ID", "Name"))
```

My Model where enums are created :

```
public enum Ntypes{
  halfday
  casual
}
```

My Controller :

```
ViewBag.MyTransaction = db.LeaveTypes.ToList(); //get the table values to drop down
```

//then even I can get the hard coded values separately ............

```
ViewBag.MyTansaction = (from NewLeaveTypes t in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Ntypes))
                                select new { ID = t, Name = t.ToString()).ToList();
```

But cant get both values into one dropdownlist. 
Plzzzz Help.

Thanks...........

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate the 2 lists together:

```
var nTypes = Enum
    .GetValues(typeof(Ntypes))
    .Select(t => new LeaveType { ID = t, Name = t.ToString())
    .ToList();
ViewBag.MyTransaction = db.LeaveTypes.ToList().Concat(nTypes);
```

and then in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.MyTransaction.Status, 
    new SelectList(ViewBag.MyTransaction, "ID", "Name")
)
```